# boost::signals2 возможен ли асинхронный запуск?

Tags: c++, boost, signal

Можно ли асинхронно запустить слоты ? К примеру следующий код работает синхронно, где после вызова первого сигнала, второй сигнал дожидается завершения работы первого. Можно ли сделать так что бы обе функции вызвались асинхронно не меняя при этом тела самих функций (лямбд в данном случае) ?

```
int main()
{
    boost::signals2::signal<void(void)> TestSignal;

    TestSignal.connect([]()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        Sleep(6000);
    });

    TestSignal.connect([]()
    {
        std::cout << "World" << std::endl;
    });

    TestSignal();

    return 0;
}
```

Метод Sleep - задерживает поток на n милисекунд

Comment: За асинхронностью - это вам в boost.asio. И да, у вас тут всего один сигнал, на который подписаны два обработчика.

Comment: @VTT про сигналы верно подметили, слоты имел ввиду. А можно пример небольшой? А то как уже говорил с boost  работал не разу, только начинаю ее изучать понемногу.